# WPF binding / dependency property (List)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dependencies

I have an application that displays 2 list boxes of images.  They are the same images, but in different order.  Comparing the position in each order is relevant, so I use a separate List for each listbox.

The List has several dependency properties, just so I can display several attributes as well as the image itself.

So simply put, I populate 2 List instances.  The properties in the ImageCrawler class are all dependency properties.

I'm barely getting a proper grasp around MVVM, so pardon this if it's ugly--I use another class - ViewModel, which holds 2 lists, also dep. properties as follows:

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{

    public List<ImageCrawler> Box1
    {
        get { return (List<ImageCrawler>)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Box1", typeof(List<ImageCrawler>), typeof(ViewModel));





    public List<ImageCrawler> Box2
    {
        get { return (List<ImageCrawler>)GetValue(Image2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Image2Property, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Image2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Box2", typeof(List<ImageCrawler>), typeof(ViewModel));

}
```

So those 2 lists are stored in this class.

The problem is binding.  Here is my code for one of the listboxes (mirrored in the other) in XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Box1}"
         DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"
         x:Name="ImageBox1"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Margin="10,109,0,10"
         Width="173"
         SelectionChanged="ImageBox1_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}">
            <SolidColorBrush.Color>#FF3399FF</SolidColorBrush.Color>
        </SolidColorBrush>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

That StaticResource is made available in the App.xaml here:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Application.Resources>
```

So the way those lists are populated... 
First, I have this field in the MainWindow:

```
public static ViewModel view = Application.Current.FindResource("ViewModel") as ViewModel;
```

...which as far as I understand, refers to the instance in the App.xaml.

A button is clicked, so the logic gets the lists of ImageCrawler objects, puts them in the list, and then assigns the list to the view variable defined above...but the binding doesn't work :(...  Everything else does...so I do this to assign the list I just acquired to the view:

```
view.Box1 = Box1;
```

...where Box1 is the List variable...
EDIT:  I'm still confused by this part...and wonder if it's a problem.  I'm still creating this "view" variable FROM the XAML instance..and assigning the lists to IT...  I feel like I need to SET the properties of the XAML instance of ViewModel...not get it to a variable and set THAT...  But don't see how to...or how that works :/

and if I do this:

```
ImageBox1.ItemsSource = view.Box1;
```

...then it works perfectly (minus a memory leak that's driving me nuts, but that's another story :) )...but I can't seem to figure out why setting the ItemsSource in the XAML won't work.

Comment: Check the 'Output' window. Often binding errors will be written there.

Comment: Showing my newbie-ness to programming hehe...here is the error:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Box1' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='Scope')'. BindingExpression:Path=Box1; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name='Scope'); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='ImageBox1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

However, I think that was from me trying to use DataContext=this; in the MainWindow...which I don't think is right since I set it in XAML...tried removing that...and now I don't see anything forthcoming...

Comment: That's interesting. It's looking for the `Box1` property on the `MainWindow` rather than your `ViewModel` - meaning the `ListBox`'s `DataContext` is the `MainWindow` not the `ViewModel`. Either the example code you pasted above is not what your actual code looks like or you are setting the `DataContext` property somewhere else.

Comment: Yup see the end of my last comment.  I was toying with it before and tried setting it in MainWindow and forgot to remove it.  Tried again without that and didn't see anything as helpful in the Output after I removed it.  Thanks for the thought though, now I know to look there :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the ListBox's DataContext at all. Instead of creating the ViewModel as resource, assign it directly to the Window's DataContext, and let the DataContent be inherited by child elements:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
...

<!-- ListBox DataContext is inherited from Window -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Box1}" ...>
```

In code behind you would get access to the ViewModel instance like this:

```
private void someMethodInMainWindow()
{
    var viewModel = (ViewModel)DataContext;
    viewModel.Box1 = ...
}
```

Comment: Changing the order didn't do anything.  I tried defining the DataContext as suggested (and removed StaticResource).  Only thing I left alone was the way I accessed the instance of ViewModel.  When I tried defining it as you did, I got a syntax complaint under the "DataContext" part - A field initializer cannot reference a non-static field...etc...  Anyhoo, unfortunately I saw no change in behavior.  Thanks though :).

Comment: See my edit. You're not supposed to access the DataContext when you initialize a MainWindow class member.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  Ok tried that, but the result is still the same.  Works fine if I manually set ItemsSource in the codebehind, but the binding from XAML doesn't work...  It still seems like I'm putting the info into the viewModel variable created from the app.xaml instance, and not modifying the app.xaml instance itself...but I'm not sure how.